# Chess program that will play an opening against me?

Tags: opening, software

Is there a chess program that will play a specific opening against me?  The reason being is that I want to practice against the Ruy Lopez, for example and I want a computer to play up to Bb5.  Is there program that can do this, paid or free?

Comment: It's not really an answer, but it seems to me that it would be trivial to set up a board position at `3. Bb5` and make the computer play it from there. A little more effort than forcing an opening book, but it should work.

Comment: @JonathanGarber That is how I do it with Crafty.

Answer (score 6):

[Fritz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_%28chess%29) published by ChessBase can do it for you.

Let's see [this tutorial](http://www.chesscentral.com/Making_Chess_Opening_Book_a/Play_Chess_Opening_a/136.htm) to force Fritz to play specific opening.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [LucasChess](http://lucaschess.pythonanywhere.com/). And you can chose as opponent any engine you like or dozens of preconfigured opponents with various personalities.

Comment: As far as I can tell (it's not very clear after a solid 2 minutes searching) this is for Windows only. Do you know if this is correct?

Comment: There have at least been attempts to port LucasChess to Linux. See there: http://lucaschess.blogspot.com/2015/05/version-904-playable-version-in-linux.html.  I don't know if current versions are available for Linux.  
And it seems to run in Wine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJOSCJnjJ7c